# Fatal Error in magento 2.2.2

Tags: fatal-error, magento2.2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.2 with the theme. Initially, everything worked fine. Suddenly it shows the error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function unserialize() on null in /var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php:160 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php(543): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->populateAdditionalDataEavAttribute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor)) #1
/var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Model/Plugin/Configurable.php(53): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->isVisualSwatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor)) #2
/var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Swatches\Model\Plugin\Configurable->afterGetUsedProductCollection(Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor), Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\Collection\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #3
/var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/framework/Intercepti in /var/www/html/4061/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php on line 160
```

[image]

Comment: have you created any custom attribute for the product?

Comment: facing the same issue yes the theme it self have created some attributes when installed the theme

Comment: How do you solve this issue? I am also facing this same issue. Please help with the solution.